# jQuery Date Range Select on Calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I am trying to add functionality to jQuery Date Picker that will allow me to select a date range similar to [travelocity.com](https://www.travelocity.com/Hotels) and [Kayak.com](https://www.kayak.com/)

[image]

I have the range selection working fine but what I am trying to do is once I select one date I want to show dates being highlighted while moving to the second date. Similar function to above mentioned sites.

The plugin I am using is [jQuery Datepicker](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html#range)

Comment: is this extension any good? https://tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/ Or this one http://longbill.github.io/jquery-date-range-picker/

Comment: @ADyson the second link you gave seems to have the functionality I am after when it comes to highlighting while selecting. Thank you!

Comment: No worries. I'm surprised you didn't find it by searching yourself, it was on the first page in google.

Comment: lol, I had the other script I was working on that had most of the functionality and I looked at a couple more out there. Had just invested to much time to give up on the one I initially started with.

Comment: @ADyson it worked perfect. Much easier to style and configure too. Thanks again!